# Queue events to fire every 350ms with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I have a keyboard event that causes an animation to play. It's possible for the user to produce more events than the rate that the animation plays so I want to create a queue that will eventually empty firing one by one after a certain amount of delay.

Desired marble diagram:

```
=================================================

user:    START|a-b-c-----------------------------

result:  START|-350ms--a--350ms--b--350ms--c-----

=================================================
```

The `user` fires 3 events rapidly (`a` `b` `c`). After event `a` fires, 350ms timer starts. After that timer is finishes, the `result` fires `a` and starts another 350ms timer. After that timer is done it fires `b`. Basically, if a timer is in progress, I want to add it to the queue and emit it later. The rate cannot exceed 350ms and I want every event.

I want to throttle the output of the events to 350ms but I don't want to use the `throttle` operator because I don't want to loose any events (I want `a`, `b`, and `c` to fire).

A Javascript RxJS solution is preferred but I'll accept any answer with Rx operators in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
import { fromEvent, concat, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, concatMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

fromEvent(document, 'keypress')
.pipe(
  filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.code === 'Space'),
  concatMap(() => timer(350))
).subscribe(console.log)
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/keypress-throttle?file=index.ts)

---

Edit: The `concat()` operator is redundant. Removed.